# javazoom (jLayer) for commercial use

Tags: java, android, mp3, decoding

Has anyone ever used [jLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) for a commercial android/java application ?

I have contacted them by email asking if it is possible to use their mp3 decoding library for my application where I'm planning to put ads, but still got no reply from them.

Please do not tell me "Read LGPL" as I it is not very clear to me :)

From what I found on the internet, if you do not modify their library and link it just like external library then you can use it in any type of project(commercial/non-commerical). Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LGPL basically means you can use it as is for any type of project.  If you change the library, you must provide the changes to the library, but not any of the code for the rest of your project.